# Set Prefix to Spring Micrometer Merics using Statsd and Datadog

Tags: spring, spring-boot, datadog, micrometer, statsd

I'm trying to Implement Custom Metrics Integration for my App. Using the following setup

```
// DogStatsd Metrics Integration with MicroMeter
implementation group: 'io.micrometer', name: 'micrometer-registry-statsd', version: '1.7.2'
```

Custom Spring Configuration Added for the application

```
@Configuration
public class MetricConfiguration {

private final MeterRegistry meterRegistry;

@Value("${management.metrics.export.statsd.prefix}")
private String prefix;

@Autowired
public MetricConfiguration(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
    this.meterRegistry = meterRegistry;
}

@Bean
public MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> metricsCommonTags() {
    return registry -> registry.config().meterFilter(new MeterFilter() {
        @Override
        public Meter.Id map(Meter.Id id) {
            if (!id.getName().startsWith(prefix)) {
                return id.withName(prefix + "." + id.getName());
            } else {
                return id;
            }
        }
    });
}

@Bean
public TimedAspect timedAspect() {
    return new TimedAspect(meterRegistry);
}
}
```

YAML Configuration for  Metrics

```
management:
  metrics:
   enable:
    jvm: false
    process: false
    tomcat: false
    system: false
    logback: false
   distribution:
    slo:
      http.server.requests: 50ms
    percentiles-histogram:
      http.server.requests: true
    percentiles:
      http.server.requests: 0.99
  export:
    statsd:
      enabled: false
      flavor: datadog
      host: ${DD_AGENT_HOST}
      port: 8125
      prefix: ${spring.application.name}
  endpoints:
    enabled-by-default: true
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
 endpoint:
   metrics:
     enabled: true
   health:
     enabled: true
     show-components: "always"
     show-details: "always"
```

Trying to set the prefix to all the custom metrics, but after setting the prefix the excluded metrics are breaking are started showing in the **/actuator/metrics** response.

The response looks like below:

```
{
 names: [
        "my-service.http.server.requests",
        "my-service.jvm.buffer.count",
        "my-service.jvm.buffer.memory.used",
        "my-service.jvm.buffer.total.capacity",
        "my-service.jvm.classes.loaded",
        "my-service.jvm.classes.unloaded",
        "my-service.jvm.gc.live.data.size",
        "my-service.jvm.gc.max.data.size",
        "my-service.jvm.gc.memory.allocated",
        "my-service.logback.events",
        "my-service.process.cpu.usage",
        "my-service.process.files.max",
        "my-service.process.files.open",
        "my-service.process.start.time",
        "my-service.process.uptime",
        "my-service.system.cpu.count",
        "my-service.system.cpu.usage",
        "my-service.system.load.average.1m",
        "my-service.tomcat.sessions.active.current",
        "my-service.tomcat.sessions.active.max",
        "my-service.tomcat.sessions.alive.max",
        "my-service.tomcat.sessions.created",
        "my-service.tomcat.sessions.expired",
        "my-service.tomcat.sessions.rejected"
        ]
 }
```

Comment: ` after setting the prefix the excluded metrics are breaking are started showing in the /actuator/metrics response` I'm not sure I understand what is breaking. It appears that you have a prefix. You also mention 'excluding' something. What is intended to be excluded that isn't being excluded?

Comment: @checketts. As you see in my configuration, I have set management.metrics.enable.jvm=false, But those jvm metrics are still visible in my actuator response.

Comment: If you don't set the prefix, is the `enable.jvm=false` working correctly? Or should this question ignore the prefix aspect and be renamed to 'How to disable Micrometer jvm metrics via config?'